# How does one tell if something is out-of-date?

Tags: discussion, old-questions

I am researching CMS options on SO and I worry that some answers may be out of date, but I have no idea.  I wanted to understand how out-of-date content is managed.  I see related information for when one knows something already, but I don't see *How does one tell if a question and its answers are out-of-date?*  Often it is too painful to try answers and feed back results.

Is there perhaps any way to view date-related information about the voting history (e.g., when votes were cast or how much recent activity)?

Here is related info I have found:

- Some helpful solutions for known out-of-date content at [Questions... now out of date...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73953/questions-with-once-good-answers-that-are-now-out-of-date-and-need-updates)
- Advice for managing our answers at [My answer down-voted... out of date](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74571/my-answer-down-voted-because-it-had-just-recently-become-out-of-date).
- I found discussion helpful at the unpopular question, [SO tag for time-sensitive questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36162/so-tag-for-time-sensitive-questions)
- An older suggestion at [Keeping Answers Up-to-Date...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28988/keeping-answers-up-to-date-a-suggestion), which wasn't adopted.

Perhaps I searched badly, but it's been a long day and I think it just as likely that the answer I seek is not yet on meta.

For example, a comment on [What is a good CMS... ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184742/what-is-a-good-cms-written-in-python-and-not-plone) rules out one option (Skeletonz), but beyond that I cannot tell what is better: highly voted or more recent answers.  (I'm not leaning this way for CMS.)

Comment: Adding to the question, I also think there are some links in questions and answers which are no more available. We should know such questions and answers too...